# iOS 13.4 / 13.5 / 13.5.1 : pointer (pointerup) events missing

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, pointer-events, ios13.4

I made a simple HTML page in which I listen to the **pointerup** event (each triggered event displays a log on the page).

*CodePen link* : https://codepen.io/rlebosse/pen/JjGYqRV

Since **iOS 13.4 (13.5 / 13.5.1 too)**, when I double tap on the page, there is only ONE "**pointerup**" log displayed.
I tried using a real device (**iPhone XR / iPhone 11 Simulator**).

When I double tap, there is a "**pointerup**" event that is missing, thus not catched.

With a **iPhone 11 Simulator** with **iOS 13.3**, I have the right amount of "**pointerup**" events : two (first and second tap).

Can you help me with this issue ? Is there a way to make both being catched ?

Thanks in advance !

The code :

```
<body>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
      p {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="observing-events-log" class="log">
      <strong>Objects events</strong>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function logObservingEvent(eventName) {
        var el = document.getElementById("observing-events-log");
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(eventName));
        el.appendChild(para);
      }
      document.body.addEventListener('pointerup', (ev) => {
        logObservingEvent("pointerup");
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</body>
```

Comment: any solution???